# How do CNNs or RNNs "stack the feature of nodes by a specific order"?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, terminology, geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks

I am trying to understand the following statement taken from the paper [Graph Neural Networks: A Review of Methods and Applications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.08434.pdf) (2019).

> Standard neural networks like CNNs and RNNs cannot handle the graph input properly in that they stack the feature of nodes by a specific order.

This statement is confusing to me. I have not used CNNs/RNNs for non-Euclidean data before, so perhaps that's where my understanding falls off.

How do CNNs/RNNs stack the feature of nodes by a specific order?